# Can I use mount command to "increase" my internal hard disk capacity using a USB drive?

Tags: mount

The internal hard disk of my home server is full and since it's not possible to upgrade it I got a USB disk.

All my home XBMC and other download services are perfectly working and configured to access and save data in `/home/pitto/download`.

Can I increase the amount of space to save data simply mounting my new disk (/dev/sda) this way?

```
root@jeeves:/home/pitto/download# df -h
File system           Dim. Usati Disp. Uso% Montato su
/dev/hda3              71G   66G  1,1G  99% /
tmpfs                 504M     0  504M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  499M  132K  499M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 504M     0  504M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda              459G  199M  435G   1% /home/pitto/download
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, and why not?

More, you could even mount it e.g. to `/mnt`, and then use the bind option or symlinks to substitute your `/home/user/{Downloads,Pictures,Music,Videos,Documents,...}`.

Comment: Great, then!
But I don't understand just one thing... 
After mounting succesfully...
If I move a file to /home/pitto/download where will it end? 
In local disk or external usb?

Comment: On the external USB, of course. You can see that by unmounting -- the download directory will become empty.

Comment: Mh that's not what I really wanted but copying data on the external usb took a second so now it works as I wanted! :D Thanks!

Comment: I can add that to use my download station (a "mini" transmission server) flawlessly instead of using the mount command it's way better to change /etc/fstab accordingly :)